# Can't submit a 2nd form through modal on same Flask route with FlaskForm

Tags: flask, post, routes, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a db search homepage that returns matching results and then gives you the ability to save that search criteria to your user profile, but not getting the loop-nested code to execute.  I'm using Flask, FlaskForm, FlaskLogin, and MongoDB.

My search results homepage route has 2 forms
1.) form = VendorSearchForm - this is the db search criteria.
2.) form2 = SaveSearchForm - this allows you to add a title and brief description of the saved search criteria.

**routes.py**

```
@main.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
@main.route("/home", methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():

    form = VendorSearchForm()

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        mainQuery = form.data   
        del mainQuery['submit']
        del mainQuery['csrf_token']
        return redirect(url_for('main.main_search_results', mainQuery = mainQuery ))

    return render_template('home.html',title = "foo",form = form)

@main.route("/home/results/<mainQuery>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main_search_results(mainQuery):
   
    form = VendorSearchForm()
    form2 = SaveSearchForm()

    #displays the search results and keeps the search criteria
    #populated for follow-on searches
    if request.method == "GET": 
        mainQuery = eval(mainQuery)
        for key, value in mainQuery.items(): 
            if key in form.data:
                form[key].data = value 
        bools = [bool(x) for x in mainQuery.values()]
        if any(bools):     
            searchResults = query_vendors(mainQuery)
        else:
            searchResults = ['No search criteria was entered. Please try again.']
             
    #A new search or follow-on is submitted through a POST request using 'form'
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        mainQuery = form.data   
        del mainQuery['submit']
        del mainQuery['csrf_token']
        return redirect(url_for('main.main_search_results', mainQuery = mainQuery ))
    
    #This loop controls the posting of 'form2' that saves the search to the user's profile.
    #This option is only available if the user is logged in. 
    if request.method == "POST" and form2.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.add_saved_search(eval(mainQuery))
        flash('Your search has been saved', 'success')
        redirect(url_for('main.main_search_results', mainQuery = mainQuery ))

    return render_template('search_results.html',METHOD = "GET",title = "Results", form=form, form2=form2, mainQuery=mainQuery, searchResults=searchResults)
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
                <form action="" method="POST" >
                    {{ form.csrf_token }}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Title </legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.region.label(class="form-control-label") }} 
                            {% if form.region.errors %} 
                                {{ form.region(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback"> 
                                    {% for error in form.region.errors %}
                                        <span> {{error}} </span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form.region(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 
                            {% endif%}
                        </div>
                       <!-- multiple repeating divs for each form field omitted here for brevity -->
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                    </div>     
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class = col-md-7>
                {% block searchResults %} 
                {% endblock %}
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**search_results.html**

```
{% extends "home.html" %}

{% block searchResults %}
        <h5> Save this Search </h5>
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %} 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#saveSearchModal">Save this Search?</button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="saveSearchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="saveSearchModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="saveSearchModalLabel">Save this Search</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="" method="POST" >
                                    {{ form2.csrf_token }}
                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ form2.search_name.label(class="form-control-label") }} 
                                            {% if form2.search_name.errors %} 
                                                {{ form2.search_name(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                                <div class="invalid-feedback"> 
                                                    {% for error in form2.search_name.errors %}
                                                        <span> {{error}} </span>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </div>
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{ form2.search_name(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 
                                            {% endif%}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ form2.description.label(class="form-control-label") }} 
                                            {% if form2.description.errors %} 
                                                {{ form2.description(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                                <div class="invalid-feedback"> 
                                                    {% for error in form2.description.errors %}
                                                        <span> {{error}} </span>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </div>
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{ form2.description(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 
                                            {% endif%}
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                            {{ form2.save(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>     
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ url_for('users.login') }}">Login to save this search</a>
            {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% for result in searchResults %}
    <div class="card">
        {{ result }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**forms**

```
class VendorSearchForm(FlaskForm):
    business_name = SearchField('Business Name')
    region = MultiCheckBoxField('Region', choices = cities)
    business_type = MultiCheckBoxField('Business Type', choices = vendorTypes)
    business_size = MultiCheckBoxField('Business Size', choices = businessSize)
    audience = MultiCheckBoxField('Audience Ages', choices = audienceAges)
    events = MultiCheckBoxField('Parties', choices = eventTypes)
    submit = SubmitField('Search')

class SaveSearchForm(FlaskForm): 
    search_name = StringField('Search Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max =30)])
    description = StringField('Description', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max =100)])
    save = SubmitField('Save Search')
```

I'd like to have form2 populate as a modal, then once submitted run the function "add_saved_search" to add the query dict to the db. You can only save search if you have a user account, and I am using the html 'if current_user.is_authenticated' loop to prevent the 'Save Search?' button from displaying to control this action.

The modal is displaying correctly, but when I press 'Save Search' t submit form2 it is not running the code in the loop, but I do see the POST request.  I'm trying to differentiate the POST requests with different if loops for both forms, but it seems like it's only executing the loop for the 1st form - 'form'.

[requests screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07fwZ.png)

I've tried changing the form2 submit field name from 'submit'  to 'save' but that did not work.  Nesting the 2nd if request.method == "POST" loop under the 1st as an elif also did not work.